# What's a simple, fast 3D engine that can be accessed from Python?

Tags: python, terrain, fractals, 3d-engine

I'm trying out fractal terrain generators (I'm thinking of doing some rather in-depth stuff, with trees and suchlike), and I want a fast 3D engine. The only thing that would be required of it is being able to draw lines, surfaces, move the camera, and simplicity.

Comment: You may want to check out the game developer stack exchange for this question:
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8290/whats-the-best-python-3d-engine

Comment: I do not need models or whatnot.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at pyopengl http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/

It is not so much an engine, but rather a low level interface to the hardware.

You would need to learn OpenGL to use this effectively, there are some good tutorials at http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lessons_01__05/22004/

Answer (score 0):

There is a long list of game/graphics engines here which would be worth going through:

- http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGameLibraries
- http://www.vrplumber.com/py3d.py

[Soya3D](http://home.gna.org/oomadness/en/soya3d/index.html) looks interesting, but last update is from 2010..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [pyIrrlicht](http://pir.sourceforge.net).